# Select Multiple Items in SwiftUI List

Tags: swiftui

In UIKit you can select multiple rows of a UITableView by using [allowsMultipleSelection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614938-allowsmultipleselection) - can this be done with the List in SwiftUI?

Comment: Yes. Check out how to use `EditButton`. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-enable-editing-on-a-list-using-editbutton

Comment: @dfd - Multiple selection and multi-row editing seem like different things.

Comment: @Rob, not sure what you mean. Technically, `allowsMultipleSelection` doesn't exist (yet) for a `List`. But functionally, if you use an `EditButton` with a List, you can select multiple rows, albeit *very* differently than a `UITableView`.

Comment: That’s exactly what I mean. They’re analogous, but completely different things.

Comment: Could I programmatically tap the EditButton so that when the view is presented multiple items can be selected? Use case is applying multiple tags to a File

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The only way to get multiple selection in SwiftUI right now is by using `EditButton`. However, that's not the only instance you might want to use multiple selection, and it would probably confuse users if you used `EditButton` multiple selection when you're not actually trying to edit anything.

I assume what you're really looking for is something like this:

[image]

Below is the code I wrote to create this:

```swift
struct MultipleSelectionList: View {
    @State var items: [String] = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Pears", "Mangos", "Grapefruit"]
    @State var selections: [String] = []

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                MultipleSelectionRow(title: item, isSelected: self.selections.contains(item)) {
                    if self.selections.contains(item) {
                        self.selections.removeAll(where: { $0 == item })
                    }
                    else {
                        self.selections.append(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct MultipleSelectionRow: View {
    var title: String
    var isSelected: Bool
    var action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: self.action) {
            HStack {
                Text(self.title)
                if self.isSelected {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @graycampbell. Your solution is great.

Comment: My full solution based on your example: https://www.pawelmadej.com/post/multi-select-picker-for-swiftui/

Comment: @graycampbell Instead of using state I'm using "@Binding" and I get weird behaviour doing that sometimes. For instance clicking on a row will push (it's inside a NavigationView) a new view of the MultipleSelectionList...

Comment: @PeterWarbo It’s hard to say why that would be happening without seeing your code. If you want to post a new question and then link to it here, I’d be happy to take a look at it

Comment: Bless you. Best solution. With a Stateable List you can send back to another view if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

First add this to your view

```
@State var selectedItems = Set<UUID>()
```

The type of the `Set` depends on the type you use to `id:` the items in the `ForEach`

Next declare the List

```
List(selection: $selectedItems) {
    ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
        Text("\(item.name)")
    }
}
```

Now whatever you select gets added to the selectedItems `Set` remember to clear it out after you use it.

Answer (score 7):

I created a custom `ToggleStyle` as follows:

```swift
import SwiftUI


enum Fruit: String, CaseIterable, Hashable {
    case apple = "Apple"
    case orange = "Orange"
    case banana = "Banana"
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var fruits = [Bool](repeating: false, count: Fruit.allCases.count)

    var body: some View {
        Form{
            ForEach(0..<fruits.count, id:\.self){i in
                Toggle(isOn: self.$fruits[i]){
                    Text(Fruit.allCases[i].rawValue)
                }.toggleStyle(CheckmarkToggleStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CheckmarkToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: { withAnimation { configuration.$isOn.wrappedValue.toggle() }}){
                HStack{
                    configuration.label.foregroundColor(.primary)
                    Spacer()
                    if configuration.isOn {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark").foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternate way that uses a helper I created called `Multiselect`:

[image]

```swift
struct Fruit: Selectable {
    let name: String
    var isSelected: Bool
    var id: String { name }
}

struct FruitList: View {

    @State var fruits = [
        Fruit(name: "Apple", isSelected: true),
        Fruit(name: "Banana", isSelected: false),
        Fruit(name: "Kumquat", isSelected: true),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Number selected: \(fruits.filter { $0.isSelected }.count)")
            Multiselect(items: $fruits) { fruit in
                HStack {
                    Text(fruit.name)
                    Spacer()
                    if fruit.isSelected {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the supporting code here:

```
protocol Selectable: Identifiable {
    var name: String { get }
    var isSelected: Bool { get set }
}

struct Multiselect<T: Selectable, V: View>: View {
    @Binding var items: [T]
    var rowBuilder: (T) -> V

    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            Button(action: { self.items.toggleSelected(item) }) {
                self.rowBuilder(item)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element: Selectable {
    mutating func toggleSelected(_ item: Element) {
        if let index = firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) {
            var mutable = item
            mutable.isSelected.toggle()
            self[index] = mutable
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found an approach using a custom property wrapper that enables the selection to be modified from a child view using a `Binding`:

```swift
struct Fruit: Selectable {
    let name: String
    var isSelected: Bool
    var id: String { name }
}

struct FruitList: View {
    @State var fruits = [
        Fruit(name: "Apple", isSelected: true),
        Fruit(name: "Banana", isSelected: false),
        Fruit(name: "Kumquat", isSelected: true),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Number selected: \(fruits.filter { $0.isSelected }.count)")
            BindingList(items: $fruits) {
                FruitRow(fruit: $0)
            }
        }
    }

    struct FruitRow: View {
        @Binding var fruit: Fruit

        var body: some View {
            Button(action: { self.fruit.isSelected.toggle() }) {
                HStack {
                    Text(fruit.isSelected ? "☑" : "☐")
                    Text(fruit.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the source for `BindingList`](https://gist.github.com/ccwasden/4a5247249866f63b87af15a58bea3c12)

Answer (score 2):

my 2 cents with a super simple solution:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListDemo: View {
    @State var items = ["Pizza", "Spaghetti", "Caviar"]
    @State var selection = Set<String>()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { (item : String) in
            
            let s = selection.contains(item) ? "√" : " "
            
            HStack {
                Text(s+item)
                Spacer()
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                if  selection.contains(item) {
                    selection.remove(item)
                }
                else{
                    selection.insert(item)
                }
                print(selection)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

using string in set is sub-optimal, better to use id OR using strings with data and selection state.

Comment: Would this also be possible if you had multiple Sections? So your items would be something like `[["Pizza", "Spaghetti"], ["Caviar"]]`?

Comment: yes, but I prefer to use a viewModel or a more complex solution, a bit beyond this example.