# how to write code on swiftui project to add array field to Cloud Firestore

Tags: arrays, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am a beginner in Xcode programming, I downloaded a project from this site (https://www.raywenderlich.com/11609977-getting-started-with-cloud-firestore-and-swiftui), that allows you to add data to the firestore database,  I succeeded in adding some fields in the project, but I encountered problem that I did not know to solve:

How to write code to add data of type (Array) to the project, as is shown in the picture

[add array field to firebase cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om1t0.png)

on card.swift

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Card: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var countryCode: String
  var title: String
  var logo: String
  var streamURL: String
  var desc: String
  var status: Bool = true
  var userId: String?
}

#if DEBUG
let testData = (1...10).map { i in
  Card(countryCode: "countryCode #\(i)", title: "title #\(i)", logo: "logo #\(i)", streamURL: "streamURL #\(i)", desc: "desc #\(i)")
}
#endif
```

on newcardform.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewCardForm: View {
  private func addCard() {
    // 1
    let card = Card(countryCode: countryCode, title: title, logo: logo, streamURL: streamURL, desc: desc)
    // 2
    cardListViewModel.add(card)
    // 3
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
  }

  @ObservedObject var cardListViewModel: CardListViewModel
  @State var countryCode: String = ""
  @State var title: String = ""
  @State var logo: String = ""
  @State var streamURL: String = ""
  @State var desc: String = ""

  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30) {
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("countryCode")
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
        TextField("Enter the countryCode", text: $countryCode)
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      }
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("title")
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
        TextField("Enter the title", text: $title)
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      }
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("logo")
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
        TextField("Enter the logo link", text: $logo)
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      }
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("streamURL")
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
        TextField("Enter the streamURL", text: $streamURL)
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      }
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("desc")
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
        TextField("Enter the desc", text: $desc)
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      }
      Button(action: addCard) {
        Text("Add New Card")
          .foregroundColor(.blue)
      }
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 80, leading: 40, bottom: 0, trailing: 40))
  }
}

struct NewCardForm_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    NewCardForm(cardListViewModel: CardListViewModel())
    
  }
}
```

### EDIT :

Finally, I was able to put together a list of  genres that I want, but how can I choose two or more of them and then store them in [array] in Firebase?

Here is what I have modified :

in NewCardForm.swift

```
    import SwiftUI

struct NewCardForm: View {
  private func addCard() {
    // 1
    let card = Card(countryCode: countryCode, title: title, logo: logo, streamURL: streamURL, desc: desc, genres: [])
    // 2
    cardListViewModel.add(card)
    // 3
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
  }

  @ObservedObject var cardListViewModel: CardListViewModel
  @State var countryCode: String = ""
  @State var title: String = ""
  @State var logo: String = ""
  @State var streamURL: String = ""
  @State var desc: String = ""
  @State var items: [String] = ["talk", "news", "poem", "songs"]
  @State var selections: [String] = []
  
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
  var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30) {
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("countryCode")
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
        TextField("Enter the countryCode", text: $countryCode)
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      }
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("title")
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
        TextField("Enter the title", text: $title)
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      }
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("logo")
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
        TextField("Enter the logo link", text: $logo)
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      }
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("streamURL")
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
        TextField("Enter the streamURL", text: $streamURL)
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      }
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        Text("desc")
          .foregroundColor(.gray)
       // TextField("Enter the desc", text: $desc)
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        List {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { string in
                        Text(string)
                    }
      }
    
        Button(action: addCard) {
        Text("Add New Card")
          .foregroundColor(.blue)
      }
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
  }
}

struct NewCardForm_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    NewCardForm(cardListViewModel: CardListViewModel())
    
  }
}
```

}

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1ovT.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. In general, you should show some of the code you've written (not links to codes) and then show where you're having a problem: [ask]. In this case, do you need to know how to define an Array in Swift?

Comment: I don't know how to write swift code here

Comment: How to write Swift code on Stack Overflow? You can paste it in the question -- there are formatters to help you include the `{ }` button in the editor.

Comment: i do it , thank you

Comment: I see that you have edited the question, but what's your question now then?

Comment: same qustion "How to write code to add data of type (Array) to the project, as is shown in the picture" , i dont know how write code

Answer (score 0):

To add an array that matches your Firestore structure, you can add this to your `Card` model:

```
var genress : [String]
```

You'll also need to add that parameter to your `testData` -- Xcode should give you an error with a "Fix" option that will give you an autocomplete to fix it and give it a parameter. You could, for example, use just `genress: []` or `genress: ["item1", "item2"]`.

By the way, "genress" *looks* like it could be a misspelling. If so, you'd need to change it both your your model *and* in Firestore (maybe you meant "genres"?).

Comment: yes , i mean "genres" ,  I will try it now

Comment: It works well, but how can I enter data in genres field, so it  not predefined data? For example, I have a BBC radio what genres is broadcast:
News
Songs
Dialogues
Other (Write)
In other words, species are as a drop-down list and chose more than one.

Comment: There's not really a built-in SwiftUI component for that. You could display the available items in a `List` and then keep track of which are selected. You could have a list of `Toggle`s and turn them on or off, etc. Take a look at this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022615/select-multiple-items-in-swiftui-list

Comment: Actually the link is useful, but I don't know how to put it in my code?  Where am I supposed to adjust the code? How to replace genres field with such this list? https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCyKc.png

Comment: Look at the code. See where they have "Apples", "Oranges", etc? Replace those with your genres.

Comment: Can I write the code here?  Or press  answer question button? To explain my problem

Comment: Edit your original question.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't do it, I wasted about an hour useless, can you please help me?  How do I replace  genres field with a multiple-selection menu?