# SwiftUI - list with multi-select (not a custom one)

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui, multi-select

How to make a list with multi-select in SwiftUI?
I know I can make a custom one like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57023746/12315994

**But is there a default one already in SwiftUI?**

Here is an example of multi-select controls in Apple's Mail app:

[image: Apple Mail app]

The same controls are also used in Apple Photos when you select multiple photos.
These controls are also in Apple's official iOS Sketch Library which you can download from here: https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/

There are very similar controls in Apple's Reminders App:

[image: Apple Reminders app]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, SwiftUI's list has this capability built in. You need to provide a `Set` for the `selection` parameter of the list for multiple selections.  I'm also setting the edit mode to `.active` by default, which is optional.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = Set<String>()
    @State private var isEditMode: EditMode = .active
    
    let items = [
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
        "Item 4"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { name in
                Text(name)
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, self.$isEditMode)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about `@State private var isEditMode: EditMode = .active`.
2 questions:
1. Can you use your solution in forms? So for example, user will create new item and will see few options to (multi)select. And later I could save info about what was selected per this item?
2. Can you change background color of selected items from default grey one?

Comment: 1) In my limited experiment of trying to embed it in a `Form`, it did not seem to work. 2) Not that I know of. Perhaps there's some sort of combination of list styles and modifiers, but nothing works in an obvious way.

Comment: Thanks. I will experiment how to use it in Forms.