# SwiftUI List selection does not select

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to use a list selection for the user to zero or more days from a list. I have tried to use the solution listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56706188/how-does-one-enable-selections-in-swiftuis-list?noredirect=1&lq=1), but to no avail.

My code is given below, and I have verified edit mode is active. I should expect behaviour like in the answer linked to above.

Code:

```
struct EditView: View {

    @State var selectKeeper = Set<String>()
    var weekdays: [String] = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    @Environment(\.editMode) var mode

    var body: some View {

            Form {

                Section(header: Text("Overtime Days")) {

                    List(self.weekdays, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper) { day in
                        Text(day)
                    }

                }

            }   .navigationBarTitle(Text("My Title"))
                .padding(.top)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    print(self.mode?.value as Any)
                })

        }
}
```

The EditButton is contained in a parent view and is enabled in the following piece of code.

```
struct JobDetailHost: View {

    @Environment(\.editMode) var mode
    @Binding var jobDetails: JobDetails

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

                if self.mode?.value == .inactive {
                    JobDetailView(jobDetails: jobDetails)
                } else {
                    EditView(jobDetails: $jobDetails)
                        .onDisappear(perform: {
                            //DO STUFF...
                        })
                } 
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        .onAppear(perform: bindDraft)


    }
}
```

The table should show the selection behaviour as in the other answer, but currently it displays as just a normal list in edit mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one enable selections in SwiftUI's List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56706188/how-does-one-enable-selections-in-swiftuis-list)

Comment: I have linked to this question in my own, it does not solve my issue here as the current top answer is implemented in this code but does not have the intended behaviour.

Comment: Good point, I didn't realize.

Answer (score 2):

*Form* does stop *EditMode* from propagating (or working correctly anyway). The only way to go is to not embed it inside the *Form* and to hope it does get a fix before release (currently XcodeBeta5, reporting..).

```
import SwiftUI

struct SelectionView: View {
    @Binding var jobDetails: JobDetails

    var weekdays: [String] = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List(self.weekdays, id: \.self, selection: $jobDetails.weekdays) { day in
                Text(day)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct JobDetails: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var weekdays = Set<String>()
}

struct JobDetailsView: View {
    let jobDetails: JobDetails

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("Weekdays:")
            Text(jobDetails.weekdays.joined(separator: ", "))
        }
    }
}

struct JobDetailHost: View {

    @Environment(\.editMode) var mode
    @Binding var jobDetails: JobDetails

    var isEditing: Bool {
        return mode?.value == .inactive
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            //HStack{ Spacer(); EditButton().padding() }
            ZStack{
                if isEditing {
                    JobDetailsView(jobDetails: jobDetails)
                } else {
                    SelectionView(jobDetails: $jobDetails)
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }
}

struct JobsView: View {
    @State var jobDetails: [JobDetails] = [
        JobDetails(),
        JobDetails(),
        JobDetails(),
        JobDetails(),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List($jobDetails) { (jobDetail: Binding<JobDetails>) in
                NavigationLink(jobDetail.id.uuidString, destination: JobDetailHost(jobDetails: jobDetail))
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ListSelection2View: View {
    var body: some View {
        JobsView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a bit and the answer is not what @Fabian thought.

You need to use `.onDelete()` or else the selection bubbles will not appear:

```swift
Form {
    Section(header: Text("Overtime Days")) {
        List(self.weekdays, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper) { day in
            Text(day)
        }
        .onDelete(perform: noOp)
    }
}
.navigationBarTitle(Text("My Title"))
```