# SwiftUI Mac OS how to add selection to the List view

Tags: list, macos, swiftui, selection

It easy to create a simple list like this:

```
List { Text("Item 1") Text("Item 2") Text("Item3") }
```

But how I can add a selection like traditional NSTable?

Comment: Do you mean selection like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56706188/how-does-one-enable-selections-in-swiftuis-list?noredirect=1&lq=1?

Comment: I meant the blue Highlight bar to chose specific row, I am workin on Mac OS App

Comment: Thank you, the examples in that question helped me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
struct names {
    var id = 0
    var name = ""
}

var demoData = ["Phil Swanson", "Karen Gibbons", "Grant Kilman", "Wanda Green"]

struct SelectionDemo : View {
    @State var selectKeeper = Set<String>()

    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            List(demoData, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper){ name in
                Text(name)
            }.frame(width: 500, height: 460)
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            SelectionDemo()
        }
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Remark: you have to change Set<String>() to the type of your array or your own structure like Set<Student>

Comment: Worked for me on macOS.

Comment: For me it didn't work with custom types, i had to manually set a value for selectKeeper

Comment: On the Apple Developer forums it seemed like the key was to use `id: \.self` which worked for me even though my data already conformed to Identifiable.

Comment: @iMaddin The same here. Do you know why?