# SwiftUI List how to identify what item is selected on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

Here is what I have based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549007/swiftui-mac-os-how-to-add-selection-bar-to-the-list-view). The code currently allows the user to select a cell but I cannot distinguish *which* cell is selected or execute any code in response to the selection. In summary, how can I execute code based on the selected cell's name and execute on click. The cell currently highlights in blue where clicked, but I want to identify it and act accordingly based on that selection. Note: I am not looking to select the cell in editing mode. Also, how can I programmatically select a cell without click?

```
struct OtherView: View {
    @State var list: [String]
    @State var selectKeeper = Set<String>()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(list, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a gif demoing the selection


[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround, but the text itself has to be clicked- clicking the cell does nothing:

```
struct OtherView: View {
    @State var list: [String]
    @State var selectKeeper = Set<String>()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(list, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper) { item in
                Text(item)
                  .onTapGesture {
                     print(item)
                  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can react to the selected item by using `onChange` on your selection variable.

You can set the selection manually by simply setting the variable. This will also trigger `onChange`.

Here's some example code that will run directly in Playgrounds:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct OtherView: View {
    @State var list: [String] = ["a", "b", "c"]
    @State var selection: String?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(list, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
                .onChange(of: selection) {s in
                    // React to changes here
                    print(s)
                }
                
                Button("Select b") {
                    // Example of setting selection programmatically
                    selection = "b"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

let view = OtherView()
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
```

Answer (score 0):

List selection works in Edit mode, so here is some demo of selection usage

[image: demo]

```
struct OtherView: View {
    @State var list: [String] = ["Phil Swanson", "Karen Gibbons", "Grant Kilman", "Wanda Green"]
    @State var selectKeeper = Set<String>()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(list, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper) { item in
                if self.selectKeeper.contains(item) {
                    Text(item).bold()
                } else {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }.navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack {
                if self.selectKeeper.count != 0 {
                    Button("Send") {
                        print("Sending selected... \(self.selectKeeper)")
                    }
                }
                EditButton()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem is .navigationBarItems doesn't work on SwiftUI on macOS

Answer (score 0):

To spare you the labour pains:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: String?
    let list: [String] = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                List(selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(list, id: \.self) { item in
                        VStack {
                            Text(item)
                        }
                    }
                }
                TextField("Option", text: Binding(self.$selection) ?? .constant(""))
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

This solution deals with the problem @Isaac addressed.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u12hu.png)

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents for custom selection and actions
works in swift 5.1 / iOS14:

see:

https://gist.github.com/ingconti/49497419e5edd84a5f3be52397c76eb4

I left a lot of debug "print".. to better understand.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for implementation on macOS not on iOS

Comment: my fault, BUT: 1) a simple  #if os(iOS).... will fix,  2) I FXED GIST. So pls take an look and upvote.